# Get the path to the user's default browser

Tags: java, browser

I am trying to get the file path to the user's default browser executable so that I may open it with certain arguments. The Desktop class (to my knowledge) does not contain the necessary methods to allow me to do so.

Thank you in advance, I hope that the information I provided will suffice.

Comment: Correct, and what would those arguments be? Because they probably won't work on **all** *browsers*.

Comment: I'm using the -incognito argument for opening Chrome. The .browse() method for the Desktop class doesn't allow me to pass the argument.

Comment: Correct, and that won't work (AFAIK) if the user's browser is firefox, opera or MS edge.

Comment: I'm certain that the user's browser will be chrome. I'm not worried about cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: So there is no way that you're aware of?

Comment: Not without launching chrome directly (yourself).

Comment: I see. Thank you. I apologize for wasting your time.